# iOS shortcuts broken

Tags: ios, install, shortcuts-app

Sometimes, I can’t install and download a shortcut from outside the application which I previously installed or a self-created shortcut, but sometimes I can.

- I have enabled untrusted shortcuts.

When I tap any link to a shortcut found on the internet (both qr codes and links), it switches me to the shortcuts app, but in the shortcuts app, this shortcut never loads. When I copy link to iCloud and open it, it says "timed out". I heard that there were a few days when shortcuts were broken.

My tablet was jailbroken using checkrain and the cydia icon is still on my home screen, but the JB isn't available and I rebooted. I use a vpn ([DNSCloak](https://apps.apple.com/pl/app/dnscloak-secure-dns-client/id1452162351?l=pl)) for blocking ads, but I don’t think that iCloud is flagged as ad.

Is there any way to make them work again?

Comment: Does the VPN allow you to see a log of all blocks at the same few minutes as you get a failed install?

Comment: I can enable that, i use this one app: https://apps.apple.com/pl/app/dnscloak-secure-dns-client/id1452162351?l=pl and i think that allows recording for a while... but my bug i dont think that’s related - i have vpn all the time but this bug is only sometimes (mostly when i leave shortcuts app for a few days)

Comment: Ok - that’s a good observation.

Comment: Yeah. And what now?

Comment: You may have to wait for someone that jailbreaks to answer. I can’t make any shortcut break on our test devices like you describe. You’ll need someone to reproduce this and then solve it and then decide to post what they did. First thing I would do is erase the device and be sure my mods aren’t contributing, tbh.

Comment: mods aren't active, checkrain as i used is tetchered and fter reboot i don't have it (i rebooted and formatted PC so i dont have JB back)